# Unable to retrieve type of HTML element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to know how can we retrieve the **type** of the **element** with the tag name 
I am creating a code on a HTML form. There are all types of HTML input elements (textfield, button, datepicker).

What I want is that if the user selects a option from a drop down, disable the checkboxes. But the checkbox are generated using PHP loop and I have also passed id in the checkbox name, so I cannot use:

```
document.getElementsByName('checkbox');
```

The name of my checkbox is "checkbox", so i tried using:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

which i for disabling the checkbox but this disabled all the input element on the page. Is there any solution for this? How I could use the type attribute with it as checkbox and disable on checkbox:

```
function  disabler()
{  
     checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
     if(checkboxes.type='checkbox')
     {
        for(var i=1, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++)
        {
            checkboxes[i].disabled = true;//here i want to disable only the checkbox on page 
        }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code readably when asking for help.

Comment: okkk thnk i will keep this in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using assignment operator `=` **NOT** comparison `==`. Replace this line

```
if(checkboxes.type='checkbox')
```

with

```
if(checkboxes.type == 'checkbox')
```

or a strict comparison operator `===` (compares also variable type, e.g. `"0" === 0` is false but `"0" == 0` is true)

```
if(checkboxes.type === 'checkbox')
```

**Also** you're trying to access `type` attribute of a *collection* returned by `getElementsByTagName`. To access specific element refer to `checkboxes` as it was an array

```
if(checkboxes[0].type === 'checkbox') //accesses first checkbox element
```

To loop through all elements while checking each one if it is a checkbox do this

```
for(var i=0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
    {
        if(checkboxes[i].type === 'checkbox') {
            checkboxes[i].disabled = true;
        }
    }
```

**[Here's an example fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/z8P2K/)**

Comment: You're right that `=` is the wrong operator, but testing `checkboxes.type` is also wrong in that `checkboxes` is a list...

Comment: ya i tried
                if(checkboxes.type === 'checkbox')
but it didnt worked...!

Comment: @MeeneshJain, I edited the answer. See the last line of code.

Comment: sir i used === it makes my code non working ..... only = works fine but it disables all input on that page

Comment: Sorry, I had to update it again. Please check it now. Use the last block of code (6 lines).

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, `=` is an *assignment* operator. `==` and `===` are the equality operators (loose and strict, respectively). So:

```
if(checkboxes.type=='checkbox')  // Loose, does type conversion (not relevant here)
```

or

```
if(checkboxes.type==='checkbox') // Strict, no type conversion (not relevant here)
```

Answer (score 2):

`checkboxes` is a Node List, not a single element. You need to do the test on `checkboxes[i]`:

```
function  disabler()
{  
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for(var i=1, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++)
        {
            if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                checkboxes[i].disabled = true;
            }
        }
}
```